# String to Point Array

Tags: c#

I have string in format:

- number number2,number3 number4 etc...

for example

- 238424.441451 2704909.319341,238424.441451 2704909.319341

This numbers are point on map , now i need to parse it in point array
Something like:

```
Point[] P = new Point[] 
{ 
    new Point { X = number1, Y = number2 }, 
    new Point { X = number3, Y = number4 }, 
};
```

I never know how much string have points.
What is best method to parse it. I was start with string.split but second problem is how to splinted string write to Points array?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @KonradKokosa I'm guessing: `I was start with string.split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.Split` to separate the values:

```
string s = "238424.441451 2704909.319341,238424.441451 2704909.319341";

string[] t = s.Split(' ');

List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
foreach (string p in t)
{
    string[] xy = p.Split(',');

    points.Add(new Point { X = Convert.ToFloat(xy[0]), Y = Convert.ToFloat(xy[1]) });
}

Point[] pointsArray = points.ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 if you can make it shorter than 5 lines

Answer (score 3):

> I was start with string.split

That's a good place to start.  The question is, why did you stop?

```
var points = someString.Split(',')
                       .Select(p => new Point { X = double.Parse(p.Split[' '][0]), Y = double.Parse(p.Split[' '][1]));
```

You might also include some error checking to avoid unnecessary exceptions.  How you respond to those errors is up to you...

```
var points = new List<Point>();
var pointStrings = someString.Split(',');
foreach (var p in pointStrings)
{
    var pointString = p.Split(' ');
    if (pointString.Count() == 2)
    {
        var x = 0D;
        var y = 0D;
        if (!double.TryParse(pointString[0], out x))
            // handle error
        if (!double.TryParse(pointString[1], out y))
            // handle error
        points.Add(new Point { X = x, Y = y });
    }
    else
        // handle error
}
```